# Symfony2/Doctrine - Get id of the row which is about to be inserted

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Here is my code:

```
$cost = new Cost();

if(some_condition){
    $cost->setColumn1('some_value');
} else if(some_condition){
    $cost->setColumn2('some_value');

    /**How do I get the ID of the cost row that is about to be inserted here**/

} else if(some_condition){
    $cost->setColumn3('some_value');
}

$em->persist($cost);
$em->flush();
```

I thought of doing this:

```
    $cost = new Cost();

    if(some_condition){
        $cost->setColumn1('some_value');
    } else if(some_condition){
        $cost->setColumn2('some_value');
        $em->persist($cost);
        $em->flush();

        /**How do I get the ID of the cost row that is about to be inserted here**/
        $cost->getId();

    } else if(some_condition){
        $cost->setColumn3('some_value');
    }

    $em->persist($cost);
    $em->flush();
```

But since the $cost object is persisted and flushed twice, won't the row be inserted twice? How can I tackle this issue? Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and solved your issue

```
$cost = new Cost();

if(some_condition){
    $cost->setColumn1('some_value');
    $em->persist($cost);
} else if(some_condition){
    $cost->setColumn2('some_value');
    $em->persist($cost);
    /**How do I get the ID of the cost row that is about to be inserted here**/
    $cost->getId();

} else if(some_condition){
    $cost->setColumn3('some_value');
    $em->persist($cost);
}
$em->flush();
```

Comment: id field in costs table is auto incremented. So unless the data is inserted in the database, id is not available.

Answer (score 0):

The second example code that you shown is fine, just remove the $em->persist($cost) call from the end, you only have to persist it once. Doctrine is clever enough to figure out at the second flush that the $cost entity have been already persisted once, and it will only update the changed fields (column3 in your case).

You can take it one step further, you can pass $cost to the first flush, so use $em->flush($cost), and it will only flush that one object, and not the others. The other objects will be taken care by the flush call at the end.

Comment: Won't the last flush insert the cost row again

Comment: Or will it only update the column 3 value from the previous flush

Comment: It won't, no. Try it.